# How to upload file to folder inside another folder

Tags: php, file, upload, directory

I am using this code to upload files, but when I upload a file to one folder it works , but when I want to upload a file to folder inside a folder, it doesn't work ,, as in the following code ..

```
   $imageFile = $_FILES['origialImg']['tmp_name'];
            $filename = basename( $_FILES['origialImg']['name']);
            if(strstr($_FILES["origialImg"]["type"],"image")){
        list($width, $height) = getimagesize($imageFile);

        $src = imagecreatefromjpeg($imageFile);
        $orig_h = ($height/$width)* $orig_w;

        $tmp = imagecreatetruecolor($orig_w, $orig_h);
        imagecopyresampled($tmp, $src, 0,0,0,0,$orig_w,$orig_h,$width,$height);
        imagejpeg($tmp, $folder1."/".$folder2."/".$filename,100);
        imagedestroy($tmp);
        imagedestroy($src);
```

### edit

yes, this is the error reporting

```
Warning: imagejpeg(): Unable to open 'images/big/216389_10150266713175744_609155743_9327201_766531_n.jpg' for writing: Permission denied in /var/www/GazaPlaces/account/photos.php
```

Comment: So what's in `$folder1` and `$folder2`. Do these folders exist on your server? Do you get any error message? Do you have error_reporting and display_errors set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it works when you upload a file to a folder but it doesn't work when you upload a file to a folder in that folder?

Check the folder exists and that you have permission to upload into it, you can CHMOD the folder using your FTP client.

To see if the folder is there use: [file_exists()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php).
You can CHMOD the folder using php with [chmod()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php).

Answer (score 0):

You could split the file path and do a `ftp_chdir()` for each directory in the file path before uploading the file.

Did you check if you have write permission on the second folder?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to chmod the folder `images/big/` to make it writable for the server. you can do it within php if the folder belongs to the server and just needs write permissions. see [php's chmod](http://php.net/manual/de/function.chmod.php)

Answer (score 0):

you need to give proper permissions (writable) to the target folder from main folder.

like folder1/folder2 both have the writable permissions.